# Надавати чи віддавати?

Tags: вибір-слова, дієслова

Перевагу *надавати* чи *віддавати*?

В яких випадках треба надавати, в яких - віддавати? Чим це регулюється?

Comment: Надпвати допомогу, віддавати борг.

Answer (score 6):

#### Тлумачення

> [ВІДДАВА́ТИ](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) - Повертати назад узяте (позичене, дане, привласнене,
>   належне).
>
> [НАДАВА́ТИ](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) - що. Давати можливість мати щось, користуватися чимсь
>   і т. ін.
>
> [ПЕРЕВА́ГА](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0) - чим і без прям. дод. Якість, властивість, що вигідно
>   відрізняє кого-, що-небудь від когось, чогось.

Українська граматика 1917 року, Тимченко.

> - 172. На- - від часівникових пнів:
>
> а) має те саме значення, що й прийменник на з акузативом і льокативом:
>   на-падати на, на-скочити на, ... *(не розібрав знімок)*;
>
> б) виражає кількісний відтінок чину: на-ломити, на-брати, на-носити
>   (певну кількість).
>
> - 167. Від- (од)- віді- - від часівників і йменників:

#### Я теж маю слово

Надавати, або ж на давати, по суті означає виконати дії, які б вплинули на давати. Розглянемо приклади:

> Я надаю їй роботу, а вашiй сiм'ї – житло. Вiдтепер весь другий поверх
>   цiлком у вашому розпорядженнi. (О. Авраменко, В. Авраменко)

Означає зробити дії, щоб дати їй роботу. Зробити дії на дати.

> Гарячі промови товаришів надавали упевненості в силах. (О. Донченко)

Тобто гарячі промови не давали упевненості, а є тим чинником, що призвели на дію дати упевненості в силах.

> Щонайменше двічі на день писала [Антоніна] до нього такі листи,
>   стромляла йому в руку, передавала через Людю. (М. Коцюбинський)

Тут Антоніна не просто давала листи Дюді, а пере давала, виконала достатні дії для виконання давати.

> В перші дні дивився все, що передавали. І сільськогосподарські
>   передачі, і передачі будинку моделей .. не відбивали охоти в Миколи до
>   телевізора. (Ю. Збанацький)

Бачимо, що мова йде не про давати, тобто не просто про дію, а про достатність, закінченість дії давати. Тобто усі дії давати, які завершували. В перші дні бачив не все що давали, а все що пере давали, тобто все дійшло до адресата. Якщо ж використати слово давали, то немає гарантії, що дії закінчували.

> О, вона добре знає, яка вона вродлива!.. Чому ж не використати цю
>   перевагу, щоб влаштувати своє життя?

Пере вагу, або ж достатню вагу для того, щоб влаштувати своє життя.

> Променисте жовтневе повітря віддає медом. (З. Тулуб)

Повітря не дає медом, а від дає, тобто призводить до результату дії давати.

То що ж ми маємо:

- надавати перевагу - виконати дії, які призведуть на дію давати достатню вагу для чогось;
- віддавати перевагу - виконати дії, які є результатом від дії давати достатню вагу для чогось.

Наприклад:

- змінив колеса, щоб надати перевагу своєму автомобілю на цій дорозі;
- своїми діями я надавав допомогу людині;
- віддав перевагу автомобілю з зимовими колесами, адже погода гіршає;
- зміг віддати перевагу чомусь - тобто зробити висновки, що вага достатня;
- зміг надати перевагу чомусь - тобто виконати дії, щоб вага була достатня.

Answer (score 3):

Уживають усі три варіанти:

- відда(ва)ти перевагу -- [3160 траплянь](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&queryselector=cqlrow&cql="%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B0(%D0%B2%D0%B0)%3F%D1%82%D0%B8"+"%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0"&default_attr=lemma);
- да(ва)ти перевагу -- [187 траплянь](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&queryselector=cqlrow&cql="%D0%B4%D0%B0(%D0%B2%D0%B0)%3F%D1%82%D0%B8"+"%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0"&default_attr=lemma);
- нада(ва)ти перевагу -- [1735 траплянь](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac7&queryselector=cqlrow&cql="%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0(%D0%B2%D0%B0)%3F%D1%82%D0%B8"+"%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0"&default_attr=lemma).

*Відда(ва)ти перевагу* є навіть у словнику -- [*віддавати* в "Словнику української мови" в 20 томах](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=12373&page=407). Але не думаю, що відсутність словосполучення *нада(ва)ти перевагу* в статті *[надавати](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=54073&page=1721)* можна трактувати як аргумент проти нього -- тим більше, що воно використовується в тлумаченнях слів вибирати, класти, культивувати, над, нахилятися і цитатах до інших слів.

Чи є між ними семантична різниця, мені сказати важко. Мені особисто *відда(ва)ти перевагу* асоціюється із внутрішнім сприйняттям світу (ззовні всередину) -- "визна(ва)ти щось вагомішим" (*я віддаю перевагу яблукам* -- "я сприймаю їх як кращі ніж щось"), а *нада(ва)ти перевагу* -- із впливом на світ (зсередини назовні) -- "(з)робити щось вагомішим" (*я надаю перевагу яблукам* -- "я частіше на сніданок їм яблука ніж щось" або "я більше в садку вирощую яблука ніж щось"). Але я не можу гарантувати, що це не помилкова теорія й не суто моя особиста упередженість.

(Також є ще один аспект: якщо мова не про вибір чогось (перевагу в чиїхось очах), а про лідерство, першість, близкість до перемоги (перевагу в буквальному сенсі), то тут *віддати* й *надати* набувають тих самих значень, що й із фізичними речами: "передати, втративши самому" і "забезпечити (без конотації втрати самому)" відповідно, наприклад *на останньому колі перегонів Остап віддав свою щойно здобуту перевагу Дмитру* або *слизький мокрий асфальт надав перевагу автомобілям з гращою гумою*. Але це зовсім окреме значення слова *перевага* -- рос. "преимущество" (зазвичай же в таких словосполученнях *перевага* відповідає рос. "предпочтение", і про вжиток *віддати*/*надати* із цим значенням я писав у попередньому абзаці).)