# Чи є в українській мові відповідник слова "предпочитать", який не є словосполученням "віддавати перевагу"?

Tags: переклад, from-russian, словосполучення, словотворення

Знаходив такі варіанти перекладу слова "предпочитать":

- віддавати перевагу
- надавати перевагу
- мати за краще
- більше хотіти

Дуже часто ловлю себе на тому, що не можу знайти влучний переклад до цього слова. Завжди хочеться перекласти одним словом.

Comment: Related: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/6168/8

Comment: "Влучний переклад" не дорівнює "перекласти одним словом". Словотворення одних мов дозволяє одні конструкції, інших — інші. Скажімо, перекладіть російською "уможливити" одним словом. Але якщо ваш запит — знайти переклад чогось одним словом замість усталеного перекладу (а не знайти влучний переклад, який, на думку багатьох, існує й складається з кількох слів) — почекаємо, може, хтось щось знайде.

Comment: @P.Vowk розумію, що влучний переклад важливий, але для мене також важливе словотворення і знаходження інших способів виражатись. Особливо цікаві лаконічніші способи донесення інформації. Вивчаючи англійську, я часто дивлюсь походження тих чи інших слів і там неймовірно багато запозичень. Це мова франкенштейн.

Comment: @RomanMalkevych не розумію, на користь якої позиції ви це кажете. Добре, в англійській багато запозичень. Що ви для себе з того висновуєте?

Comment: Вам треба бути готовим не тільки шукати спосіб перекласти слово в слово, тобто не змінюючи порядок слів, а й бути готовим перефразувати речення, змінити в ньому порядок слів.

Comment: @P.Vowk я висновую з цього те, що мова таким чином може розвиватись, збагачуватись і не вважатись застарілою або не популярною. В ній з'являється більше відтінків. Це як зі словом хюґе. Просто взяти і перекласти ми його не можемо, бо це буде полотно тексту. Ми маємо знати його сенс і просто перести до своєї мови. Розумію, що запозичення треба робити в міру і знаходити золоту середину в цьому.

Comment: @RomanMalkevych мій коментар не був спрямований проти запозичень. Не розумію, до чого тут вони. Уявіть собі росіянина, який побивається, що вони перекладають "уможливити" як "сделать возможньім" або "обеспечить возможность чего-либо" тощо. Те, що певні способи словотворення не поширені в певній мові, не значить, що унеможливлюються запозичення на кшталт "хюґе". На моє переконання, ви змішуєте два окремих питання.

Comment: Не бачу нічого поганого в тім, щоб почати ОБИРАТИ, замість "віддавати перевагу".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Воліти

У деяких випадках вам могло би допомогти слово "[воліти](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=15692&page=520)" у другому значенні:

> 2. Вважати за краще.

У ГРАКу можна знайти [такі](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac14_full&tab=basic&keyword=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%8E&attrs=word%2Ctag&viewmode=sen&attr_allpos=kw&refs_up=1&shorten_refs=0&glue=0&itemsPerPage=500&structs=s%2Cg&refs=%3Ddoc.author%2C%3Ddoc.date%2C%3Ddoc.title%2C%3Ddoc.authTrans&selection=%7B%7D&showresults=1&f_tab=advanced&c_itemsPerPage=100&c_customrange=1&operations=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22iquery%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%8E%22%2C%22active%22%3Atrue%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22queryselector%22%3A%22iqueryrow%22%2C%22iquery%22%3A%22%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%8E%22%7D%2C%22id%22%3A6525%7D%5D) приклади вживання:

> **Волію** бачити на вулицях столиці краще тюрбан турецького султана, **аніж** папську тіяру (мітру) чи кардинальську шапку.

Микола Лазорський, "Степова квітка", 1963

> Я волію дивитися на родючі ниви в Сконе, аніж на голі скелі хтозна-де! — сердито відповів гусак.

Сельма Лаґерлеф, "Чудесна мандрівка Нільса Гольгерсона з дикими гусьми" 1964, переклад: Ольга Сенюк

Answer (score 4):

## Преферувати

Використовується у діяспорянських діалектах:

> Греко-католицька церква […] сильно впливала на витворення почуття національної окремішності українців, і внаслідок цього почуття покривдженості політично-суспільною системою, яка ***преферувала*** поляків — [Jan M. Małecki, Zarys dziejów Polski 1864–1939, Wydawnictwo “Znak”, Kraków 1991.](http://www.nestor.cracow.pl/Wydawnictwo/ms1/cz_4.htm)

…і навіть зустрічається на сайтах у домені `.gov.ua`:

> Виняткова внутрішня і зовнішня складність досліджуваного предмету
> спонукає відмовитися від виразного ***преферування*** тільки однієї
> методологічної позиції. — [Вадим Васютинський — Інтеракційна психологія влади](https://lib.iitta.gov.ua/26538/1/monografia.pdf)

Також цікаве пояснення:

> Among the linguistic factors which explain the phenomenon of borrowing are:
> […]
>
> - “brevity as language economization” (Pfitzner (1978) cited in Gentsch 2005, p. 8; Krysin 2008, p. 21; Styshov, 2011), **the preference of one foreign word to a two- or three-word equivalent in the donor language***, reinforced by the morphological simplicity of English (Lehnert (1986), cited in Hoffmann 2011, p. 131), e.g. ***преферувати*** instead of authentic *надавати перевагу*, *вважати за краще*; комп’ютер < *computer* instead of *електронна обчислювальна машина* — [Khrystyna Petryshyn: English loanwords in electronic media discourse in Ukraine](https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/42533/Petryshyn_master.pdf?sequence=1) (стор.7)

Вільний переклад: «схильність до використання однослівного запозиченого слова замість дво- або трьохслівного виразу у цільовій мові».

Погана новина полягає у тім, що наразі слово не є ані питомим, ані усталеним. Пошукові системи вважають його помилкою: «можливо, ви мали на увазі **перфорувати**».

Натомість, хороша новина — слово ***преференція*** має широкий вжиток, тому нема перепон від того, що ***преферувати*** також стане усталеним, якщо буде активно вживатися фактично.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133656/discussion-on-answer-by-bytebuster--------).

Comment: 1. Діяспорянські діалекти засмічені англіцизмами, не треба їх тягнути в українську мову. 2. Думаю, що у більшості випадків можливо перекласти *предпочитать* одним словом.

Answer (score 0):

*Я предпочитаю* красньіе яблоки. --

- *Мені* червоні яблука *кращі/ліпші.*
- Я *(за/в)довольняюсь* червоними яблуками.
- Я *обираю* червоні яблука.

*Предпочитаю* красньіе яблоки. --

- *Краще* червоні яблука.

Comment: Запит був на переклад одним словом. Я надав такий переклад (щонайменше для теперішнього часу), що не так?

Comment: @stegetsj ні, одне. Я заміним *я предпочитаю* на *мені ... кращі*. Кількість слів не змінилась.

Comment: @stegetsj Якщо прибрати? Прибрав.

Comment: @stegetsj даруй, тут справді одне слово на переклад "предпочитать", те, що інше слово змінює відмінок, не робить його перекладом російського дієслова. Просто змінюється узгодження.

Comment: Для прикладу вмѣст: _ѥ червоні і зелені яблока_. Вони однаковоꙓ якостьи, але умовно любю червоні. Менѣ запитують, за порадою Йола: _Які яблока красші?_ Я від такого поставєного запитання, очовидно, спершу подумаю _про загальну думку_, а не про _чому надаю перевагу я сам_. Сподѣваю ся, я достатньо ясно пояснив чому це не відповѣдь.

Comment: @stegetsj Дякую за комент, примусив мене подумати і ось: якщо ви повністю опишете ситуацію, то ваше питання відпаде. Тобто треба розуміти для чого ставлять це запитання. Наприклад, якщо ви стоїте біля ятки з яблуками і незнайомець вас таке запитав, то напевне він питає поради для себе.

Comment: @stegetsj така будова речення є звичною хіба для якихось канцеляристів. Натомість звична така *ці кращі, але (я) беру ті*.

Comment: @stegetsj там ніде не було сказано, що відповідник має не залежати від вмісту. Завжди (щонайменше в теперішньому часі) хочеться і можна перекласти одним словом, але не завжди одним і тим самим.

Comment: Добре, стій на свойому. Свою відповѣдь вже надав, твоя воля сприймати чи нѣ.

Comment: @stegetsj ❤️підхід! Щодо твого *Які яблока красші?*, то можна запитати так *Які яблука обираєш/обиреш/обрав би.* Не можу уявити ситуації де не можна перекласти одним словом. А якщо й є така, то *мені кращі* це точно краще ніж *надавати перевагу* чи *преферувати* - навіть не знаю, яке з двох гірше, настільки погані обидва.